# Javafx adding event handlers in a loop

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, event-handling

I'm trying to make a method to add SetOnMousePressed-functions to multiple nodes, and i've tried using a couple different loops etc, but i always end up with the error "Local variable x defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final." This is as far as i've gotten:

```
public static int playerSelectingCategory(int intScorecard[][], Rectangle[][] scoreboardBackground, int categoryCounter, int nrOfPlayers, boolean limitCheck)

    {
    int counter = 0;
    int y = 0;

    for(int x = 0; x<YatzyConstants.getNrCategories(); x++)
    {
    if(counter < nrOfPlayers)
    {
        if(y < YatzyConstants.getNrCategories())
        { 
            scoreboardBackground[counter][y].setOnMousePressed(e ->
            {
                    scoreboardBackground[counter][y].setFill(javafx.scene.paint.Color.ALICEBLUE);   
            });
          y++; 
        }
        counter++;

    }}
    return intScorecard[counter][y];
}
```

I originally declared everything one by one, but i have to think that there should be a more effective way of doing it. Any help is appreciated, really hit a brick wall here.

Answer (score 0):

Since `y` is modified by your code, it's not efectively final and therefore cannot be accessed from a anonymus class or lambda expression. The same is true for `counter`.

I'd recommend storing `scoreboardBackground[counter][y]` in a variable that is (effectively) `final` (that is unless the array is modified and you want to color the `Rectangle` at the position where the original rect was stored...):

```
final Rectangle rect = scoreboardBackground[counter][y];
rect.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
     rect.setFill(javafx.scene.paint.Color.ALICEBLUE);   
});
```

Or alternatively simply use the `Node` that is the source of the event:

```
final EventHandler<MouseEvent> handler = event -> {
    ((Shape) event.getSource()).setFill(javafx.scene.paint.Color.ALICEBLUE);
};

for(int x = 0; x<YatzyConstants.getNrCategories(); x++)
{
    if(counter < nrOfPlayers)
    {
        if(y < YatzyConstants.getNrCategories())
        { 
            scoreboardBackground[counter][y].setOnMousePressed(handler);
            y++; 
        }
....
```